# How to calculate the area of the convex hull of a points layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

I have a shapefile in QGIS that I have created by importing a CSV of points, using Points2One to convert to a shapefile and then importing the shape. I am now trying to calculate the are of the shape but when trying to use the field calculator I can't figure out how to get the area? Can anyone help?

[image: Area]

Comment: What do you mean? You already have the answer in your screenshot. Press OK.

Comment: The only thing I might add to Underdark's comment is that you might want to adjust your precision unless you're happy to round to the nearest meter.

Comment: ... and the areas are less than 1.000.000.000 square metres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to calculate the area of a set of points rather than a polygon which it seems isn't possible. So I converted the points to a polygon using the Points2One plugin. I could then calculate the area using the field calculator :)

[image: Area of polygon]